# What are the performance differences between Tizen web and native applications

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

There are currently 3 ways to develop a wearable application - as a web application or native C/C++ application, using Tizen Studio, or as a c# application using Visual Studio 2017.

For any given application, how do each of the 3 ways compare in terms of memory requirements, CPU usage, responsiveness and functionality?

Can they all provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't seen any Benchmark Performance Comparison Document/Chart/Video yet.

But What I can share from my experience is:

- You would receive the Most Powerful Performance from Tizen Native,
  as it resides closest to the Kernel and Device Drivers.
- Each Tizen Web API functions lies over Native API, In the end it invokes the Native functions. So, While Using Web API functions "It's always costing an additional layer". The Same clause is partially true for .NET.
- Tizen Native Offers the Widest range of API functions than Web,C#.NET

[image]

But Still, All three options are open....Chose the Best one based on your Coding Experience in C/C++, C#, HTML/CSS/JS and Project Focus (Like UI Based /Features /Use of Device Sensors etc.) and Deadline.

Answer (score 4):

First of all I have to mention that I developed Tizen projects only for Tizen Wearable, so I can't tell you anything about Mobile/Tv programs.

But I can tell you that:

1 - Web and native projects are not the same (you can't do background service in web projects)

2 - there are some similar functions in web and native but they **CAN** work not in the same way.

3 - If you have custom UI - it is better to make it in web app, but if you need to use some native Tizen functions (such as access to contacts, services, etc) - you should use native app.

4 - you can create a hybrid app (that is very important when you have custom UI and need access to native TIZEN services)

> Can they all provide the same functionality?

**NO**

> There are currently 3 ways to develop a wearable application

NO, you can't use C# on wearable (since 3.0 is a last version of tizen wearable and C# needs Tizen 4.0)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what 'background services' are impossible in tizen web? (with examples if possible) I'm trying to evaluate web vs native approach :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @tymbark Web app totally die's when you close it, so non of background services are available in web version.

Comment: there are some background capabilities for tizen web development though, like web-workers or background-category flag in the config.xml

Comment: Yeah, but Tizen doesn't guarantees that they will work

Answer (score 3):

### Tizen Application Types

The Tizen platform supports 2 primary application types:

1. **Web Application** is essentially a Web site stored on your device and built using Web-native languages, such as HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript. The Web application uses the Tizen Web Framework to interact with the native subsystems.
2. **Native Application**     is developed using C and can access more advanced device-specific features, such as camera, GPS, and accelerometer in addition to more advanced system settings and functionality.

The following figure illustrates the Tizen architecture model supporting the 2 application types.

[image]

For more info: [Click Here](https://developer.samsung.com/z/develop/creating-your-first-app)